# Get my Wifi Password (It's saved as dots, how can I see it) in WinXP?

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, passwords

I can't use Wirelesskeyview, my anti-virus keeps deleting it and I can't disable it.  Is there another way to get it?

Comment: Is it WEP? If so, you could try the aircrack route to find the password.

Comment: @Rob Alright, I'll try that now.

Comment: The only downside is you need the appropriate drivers and a compatible wireless card, it's not a definite solution.

Comment: @Rob, yeah, it didn't work.

Comment: Do you have access to tthe wirelss access point/router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start in safe mode then try the wireless key view program

Comment: Good Idea!  It worked!

Answer (score 1):

Try [Cain & Abel](http://www.oxid.it/projects.html). It has a nice local password recovery for wireless passwords.

Answer (score 0):

It's a while since I've needed to use something like this, but http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bullets_password_view.html lets you view password fields in windows that are asterisk protected.

Comment: All its showing me is |||||||| as the password which isn't right...

Comment: Network Passworts are explicitly listed as not supported in the Known Limitations section.